# Data source for Highway autonomous driving

Tags: computer-vision

I am working on a object detection system for autonomous driving.
I have tried it in controlled environments.

I would like to try it on videos taken from a camera in front of a car running on a highway.

I have seen some of those on a course I took a year ago. My question is directed to DL practitioners. Where can I find public repositories of data of this kind?

(If this is not the site for this type of question, kindly point me where in stack exchange is more appropriate)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that something like the [KITTI dataset](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/) is what you are looking for. It is a large dataset made for Autonomous Vehicle Research. You can download after providing your email.

You can also try looking at the raw [KITTI data](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/raw_data.php).

Here is a [paper](https://www.mrt.kit.edu/z/publ/download/2013/GeigerAl2013IJRR.pdf) that describes the KITTI dataset in more detail.

The [bdd100k](https://www.bdd100k.com/) dataset from [Berkley](https://bair.berkeley.edu/blog/2018/05/30/bdd/) is another good source of autonomous driving data. Similar to KITTI you will need to provide your email to download.